# What is the third parameter of a Go struct field?

Tags: go

```
type Config struct {
    CommitIndex uint64 `json:"commitIndex"`
    // TODO decide what we need to store in peer struct
    Peers []*Peer `json:"peers"`
}
```

I understand what the first two columns are,but what is `json:"commitIndex"`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's called a struct tag, they can be parsed using the [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag) package at runtime.

From https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types:

> A field declaration may be followed by an optional string literal tag, which becomes an attribute for all the fields in the corresponding field declaration.
>
> The tags are made visible through a reflection interface and take part in type identity for structs but are otherwise ignored.

Some packages that use reflection like [`json`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) and [`xml`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml) use tags to handle special cases better.

Answer (score 23):

What you are referring to is called a *tag*, and the **[Go specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)** states:

> A field declaration may be followed by an optional string literal tag,
>   which becomes an attribute for all the fields in the corresponding
>   field declaration. The tags are made visible through a reflection
>   interface and take part in type identity for structs but are otherwise
>   ignored.

```
// A struct corresponding to the TimeStamp protocol buffer.
// The tag strings define the protocol buffer field numbers.
struct {
    microsec  uint64 "field 1"
    serverIP6 uint64 "field 2"
    process   string "field 3"
}
```

This does nothing at compile time, but is used by different packages when doing runtime reflection on the struct. As Amit already pointed out, the `encoding/json` package is using it to specify marshalling/unmarshalling behaviour. The same goes with `encoding/xml`, `gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson`, etc.

The tag string is by convention a space separated string. As stated in the **[`reflect` package](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag)**:

> By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally
>   space-separated key:"value" pairs. Each key is a non-empty string
>   consisting of non-control characters other than space (U+0020 ' '),
>   quote (U+0022 '"'), and colon (U+003A ':'). Each value is quoted using
>   U+0022 '"' characters and Go string literal syntax.