# how tags of struct fields are used?

Tags: go

I do not understand how field tags in `struct` are used and when. Per https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types:

> [tag] becomes an attribute for all the fields in the corresponding field declaration

what does this mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10858787/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/25497688/6309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [tag] becomes an attribute for all the fields in the corresponding field declaration

In addition to the links above ("[What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10858787/6309)", "[go lang, struct: what is the third parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25497688/6309)") [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/wkQBj2XUj40) provides an example which does *not* come from the standard packages:

> Suppose I have the following code (see below). I use a type switch the check the type of the argument in `WhichOne()`.
>
> How do I access the tag ("`blah`" in both cases)?
> I'm I forced the use the reflection package, or can this also be done in "pure" Go?

```
type PersonAge struct {
        name string "blah"
        age  int
}

type PersonShoe struct {
        name     string "blah"
        shoesize int
}

func WhichOne(x interface{}) {
    ...
}
```

> After reading that (again), looking in `json/encode.go` and some trial and error, I have found a solution.
> To print out `"blah"` of the following structure:

```
type PersonAge struct {
        name string "blah"
        age  int
}
```

> You'll need:

```
func WhichOne(i interface{}) {
        switch t := reflect.NewValue(i).(type) {
        case *reflect.PtrValue:
                x := t.Elem().Type().(*reflect.StructType).Field(0).Tag
                println(x)
        }  
}
```

Here: `Field(0).Tag` illustrates the "becomes an attribute for all the fields in the corresponding field declaration".